# How to pass filepath as a parameter to URL using perl

Tags: perl, url, parameters

I am testing my perl code. I want to pass filepath as a paramter to the URL of the page.

The perl code is dependent on this filepath entirely.

When i set the filepath inside my perl code. (hard coded path), i am able to execute the perl code without any errors. Here is the variable

```
my $filename="\\\\sfoaepmdata.dcc.com\\folder\\data.txt";
```

If i pass it via URL, it doesnt work as expected. Can anyone suggest how to pass filepath as a variable in the URL ?

Here is what all i tried to someohow transfer $filename from url to perl code.

```
http://apmqa.dcc.com/cgi-bin/test/editor.pl?filename=\\\\sfoaepmdata.dcc.com\\folder\\data.txt
http://apmqa.dcc.com/cgi-bin/test/editor.pl?filename=\\sfoaepmdata.dcc.com\folder\data.txt 
http://apmqa.dcc.com/cgi-bin/test/editor.pl?filename=//sfoaepmdata.dcc.com/folder/data.txt
http://apmqa.dcc.com/cgi-bin/test/editor.pl?filename=////sfoaepmdata.dcc.com//folder//data.txt 
http://apmqa.dcc.com/cgi-bin/test/editor.pl?filename=file://sfoaepmdata.dcc.com/folder/data.txt
http://apmqa.dcc.com/cgi-bin/test/editor.pl?filename=file:////sfoaepmdata.dcc.com//folder//data.txt
http://apmqa.dcc.com/cgi-bin/test/editor.pl?filename=http:////sfoaepmdata.dcc.com//folder//data.txt
http://apmqa.dcc.com/cgi-bin/test/editor.pl?filename=http://sfoaepmdata.dcc.com/folder/data.txt
```

The above data may seem confusing. But please only read values after ?ffilename. Can anyone pls suggest.

I also tried passing other normal paramters and it worked. for e.g. 
$account=GEL; the filepath doesnt work.

```
http://apmqa.dcc.com/cgi-bin/test/editor.pl?account=GEL
```

Comment: See also [Perl::Dancer how to include a file path as a parameter in the URI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580916/perldancer-how-to-include-a-file-path-as-a-parameter-in-the-uri)

Comment: Ok @HåkonHægland. i will have a look in that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was pretty simple. i first need to get the user parameter converted to perl and then work on it accordingly.

```
$filename   = $cgi->param('filename');
```

By this code, we will get the filepath from the user in $filename and we can work on the required file. Hope it helps someone. thanks.

The passed parameters to the URL would be as shown below

```
?filename=\\sfoaepmdata.dcc.com\folder\data.txt
```